# Setting current user on django vanilla CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to update my model with the currently logged in user. I am using django-vanilla-views. To store a new record I am trying to use CreateView. I don't want to display user on the form, just update it automatically.

Here is my model:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And here is my view:

```
class CreateMeasurement(CreateView):
    model = Measurement
    fields = ['date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list_measurements')

    def get_form(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return super(CreateMeasurement, self).get_form(data=data, files=files, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately when accessing the view I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

I also tried to create a ModelForm for my model but got exactly the same error. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass the user to the form, so don't override the `get_form` method. You have already excluded the user `field` from the model form by setting `fields` in your view, so you shouldn't need a custom model form either.

It should be enough to override the `form_valid` method, and set the user when the form is saved.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class CreateMeasurement(CreateView):
    model = Measurement
    fields = ['date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list_measurements')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```