# How to pass logged user's id to CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I can't figure out how to pass current user's name as the post's author automatically.

If add the author `fields = ['headline', 'quote', 'author']`, the dropdown menu is shown and passed, but I need the logged user's name to be the default.

my view:

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
model = Post
user = User
fields = ['headline', 'quote']
success_url = '/index'
template_name = 'base_homepage.html'

@login_required()
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['latest_posts_list'] = Post.objects.order_by('-id')
    return super(PostCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
_id = models.ObjectIdField
headline = models.TextField(max_length=255)
quote = models.TextField(max_length=140)

creation_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False).auto_now_add

author = models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.headline[:25]
```

Comment: When you say "default" do you mean that the author select input should initially be set to the current user but can be changed *or* do you mean that the created post should always have the current user as the author?

Comment: the created post should always have the current user as the author

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting current user on django vanilla CreateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751772/setting-current-user-on-django-vanilla-createview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can patch the object in the `form_valid` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['headline', 'quote']
    success_url = '/index'
    template_name = 'base_homepage.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['latest_posts_list'] = Post.objects.order_by('-id')
        return super(PostCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) advises to
> use the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) over
> [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).
> This is safer, since if the authentication app is not yet loaded, the settings
> can still specify the name of the model. Therefore it is better to write:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
>
> class Post(models.Model):
>     # …
>     author = models.ForeignKey(
>         settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE
>     )
> ```